# UIDeviceOrientation notification not getting call after calling async method in Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am calling async method in ViewDidLoad() method. It will take time so I have added Loading overlay. but whenever I try to rotate my device I am not able to rotate until I get the response from the async method.

Comment: can you show a piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you awaiting the method? If thats the case then its normal as ViewDidLoad will not finish until the awaited code gets executed.

Dont await the method and it should rotate normally.